# Why use a BehaviorSubject as a spy in Angular2 tests instead of a plain Subject

Tags: testing, rxjs

I am in reference to the following blog post: https://vsavkin.com/three-ways-to-test-angular-2-components-dcea8e90bd8d#.he4b4rw65

In one of the tests (see below) a `BehaviorSubject` is used to **act as a spy**.

I understand the requirement for a `Subject` (`Observable` + `Observer`) but why use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of a plain `Subject`?

Can anyone please explain?

```
describe('ComposeCmp', () => {
  let actions: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  let time: CurrentTime;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // this subject acts as a "spy"
    actions = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    // dummy implementation of CurrentTime
    time = () => '2016-08-19 9:10AM';
  });

  it('emits a reply action on submit', () => {
    // a fake activated route
    const route = {
      snapshot: {
        root: {
          firstChild: { params: { id: 11 } }
        }
      }
    };
    const c = new ComposeCmp(<any>route, time, actions);

    // performing an action
    c.form.setValue({
      title: 'Categorical Imperative vs Utilitarianism',
      body: 'What is more practical in day-to-day life?'
    });
    c.onSubmit();

    // reading the emitted value from the subject
    // to make sure it matches our expectations
    expect(actions.value.conversationId).toEqual(11);
    expect(actions.value.payload).toEqual({
      title: 'Categorical Imperative vs Utilitarianism',
      body: 'What is more practical in day-to-day life?',
      createdAt: '2016-08-19 9:10AM'
    });
  });
});
```

**edit**: I have a further interrogation: at what precise point is the  `actions` `BehaviorSubject` subscribed to and by which subscribers? The component under test is given below:

```
@Component({moduleId: module.id, templateUrl: 'compose.html'})
class ComposeCmp {
  form = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    body: new FormControl('')
  });

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private currentTime: CurrentTime,
              private actions: Actions) {}

  onSubmit() {
    const routerStateRoot = this.route.snapshot.root;
    const conversationRoute = routerStateRoot.firstChild;
    const conversationId = +conversationRoute.params['id'];

    const payload = Object.assign({},
      this.form.value,
      {createdAt: this.currentTime()});

    this.actions.next({
      type: 'reply',
      conversationId: conversationId,
      payload: payload
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple :)

In testing a **spy** is something that you can track. Meaning, you can ask the spy things like "what's your value", "have you been called" or "with what arguments have you been called".

In your case the spy acts as a mock for the action stream (but I guess you already know this).

The difference between a **Subject** and a **BehaviorSubject** is best shown in a simple sample like below:

```js
const s = new Rx.Subject();
s.next(5);
console.log('Subject:', s.value);

const bs = new Rx.BehaviorSubject();
bs.next(5);
console.log('BehaviorSubject:', bs.value);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

*tl;dr;* A **BehaviorSubject** stores its latest value and you can get it via `.value`. A **Subject** doesn't store anything. In your test, you want to verify that the the correct data is pushed (`.next()`) to the action stream (`actions`). Using a `BehaviorSubject` you can test this.

---

*Why is there no subscriber needed?*

It's because invoking `next()` will also set the `value`. See the source code for `BehaviorSubject`:

```
next(value: T): void {
  super.next(this._value = value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! There one last thing I don't get: when does the subscription occur with a Subject and BehaviorSubject? I don't see any call to subscribe either in my code or in your code...

Comment: I think BehaviorSubjects are always hot (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html). So you do not need a subscriber.

Comment: Can you point where it says that a hot observable does not need a subscriber? I was not aware of that.

Comment: Do you rather mean to say that subscription starts right at the time of creation of hot observables?

Comment: I checked the source code. I was wrong. Has nothing to do with hot/cold. Will update my answer.

Comment: I am having a look at the source code. I am still not clear where the subscription occurs. By looking at specs for BehaviorSubject one can see that there are no call to subscribe see: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/test-file/spec-js/subjects/BehaviorSubject-spec.js.html whereas the specs for Subject show uses of subscribe. Any idea why that is?

Comment: In your code above there is no subscription. For testing purposes it's not necessary.

Comment: You're right. And this begs the following question: why use an Observable (a subclass thereof) in the tests?

Comment: Because you can not call `.next()` on an Observable.

Comment: OK. I see. Just because of the following call **this.actions.next({** in the component?